# Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] or Current.User.Identity.Name Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I'm using forms authentication, with the application pool set to classic I've enabled forms authentication and anonymous access, and I've disabled windows authentication. I'm still unable to read the LOGON_USER or IPrincipal.Identity.Name.

In IE9 I've set the user authentication to pass through automatic logon with the current user name and password.

Yet I still can't retrieve the current logged in user.

What could be missing? is this a breaking change in IIS7.5 or a change in IE9?

Note I can't just enable windows auth as this site is used externally as well as internally. Plus the client wants to be directed to the login page and not challenged with the user/password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

When switching to classic it was returning a 403 status it was failing to handle the request.

In the end I altered the routes table to use extensions like so:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}.mvc/{action}/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute("Root", string.Empty, new { controller = "Login", action = "Index"});
```

Then I added a new wildcard mapping to handle the *.mvc extension.

Also make sure you are you using the correct app pool Identity in my solution I'm using NetworkService account, and I've also granted NetworkService account full permissions on the web folder.